# Android Firebase Storage: How to get file size from firebase storage file url before downloading it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I get file size from firebase storage before downloading it? I want to show file size to user so that they can see what is the exact size of the file.

I looked up https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files to check if there is any method to get particular file's size before downloading it. But I didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
StorageReference ref = storage.getReference();
StorageReference reference = ref.child("images.jpg");

reference.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
    Log.i("The size of the file is:", storageMetadata.getSizeBytes());
  }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
   @Override
   public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

    }
});
```

Using `getSizeBytes()` you will be able to get the size of the file.

`public long getSizeBytes ():`

> Returns
>   the stored Size in bytes of the StorageReference object

`public StorageMetadata ():`

> Creates a StorageMetadata object to hold metadata for a StorageReference.

For more info check this:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageMetadata.html
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata

Answer (score 4):

As posted on Firebase docs, you can get name, size, and content type of file stored on FirebaseStorage, by StorageReference `getMetaData()` method. According to Firebase docs,

> File metadata contains common properties such as name, size, and
>   contentType (often referred to as MIME type) in addition to some less
>   common ones like contentDisposition and timeCreated. This metadata can
>   be retrieved from a Cloud Storage reference using the getMetadata()
>   method.

Here's the example how to access metadata of file stored on FirebaseStorage,

```
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
StorageReference forestRef = storageRef.child("images/forest.jpg");

forestRef.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
        //here, storageMetadata contains all details about your file stored on FirebaseStorage
        Log.i("tag", "name of file: "+storageMetadata.getName());
        Log.i("tag", "size of file in bytes: "+storageMetadata.getSizeBytes());
        Log.i("tag", "content type of file: "+storageMetadata.getContentType());
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
        Log.i("tag", "Exception occur while gettig metadata: "+exception.toString());
    }
});
```