# How to get the total size of items stored in firebase cloud storage?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have a bunch of image and video posts stored for each user in a path such as: /images/posts/user_id/somevideoid.mp4

In my iOS app, I want users to be able to see how much data they are storing. Thus I want to be able to programmatically (probably using the FirebaseStorage SDK?) get the total MB or GB of that folder. What is the recommended way to do such a thing? Am I looking for an API method? Or do I have to somehow get the folder metadata from the url? Im not sure where to start.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521016/android-firebase-storage-how-to-get-file-size-from-firebase-storage-file-url-be?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762731/get-storage-space-used-in-a-folder-in-firebase-storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no per-user accounting for files stored in Cloud Storage.  You will have to keep track of that on your own as the user uploads and download files.  There is not a single API that will do this - you will need to use your own database and keep it up to date.